# How to do a has_many through with a condition based on joining another table to the join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through, rails-activerecord

I need to do a has many_through relationship in Rails, where the only records that are returned are those where the join table is attached to a particular record in another table.

I have tried in SQL, and it doesn't work. How Can I express the SQL relation below in active record style?

Here are the models:

```
class User
  has_many :organisation_roles
  has_many :organisations,
           through: :organisation_roles
end 

class OrganisationRole
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :organisation
  belongs_to :role
end

class Role
  has_many :organisation_roles
end

class Organisation

  has_many :organisation_roles
  has_many :roles, through: :organisation_roles
  has_many :users, through: :organisation_roles

  # This doesn't work
  has_many :members, 
           class_name: 'User', 
           through: :organisation_roles,
           finder_sql: Proc.new {
             %Q{
               SELECT u.*
                 FROM users u, organisation_roles ors, roles r
                WHERE ors.organisation_id = #{id} AND r.name = 'member'
       }
  }

  # This doesn't either
  has_many :managers, 
           through: :organisation_roles, 
           source: :user, 
           conditions: { organisation_roles: { role: { name: 'manager' }}}

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, although using an instance method, not has_many:

```
class Organisation
  # other stuff

  def members
    users.joins(:roles).where("roles.name = 'member'")
  end
end

class User
  # other stuff

  has_many :roles,
           through: :organisation_roles
end
```